# UnsupportedClassVersionError in Webphere 8.5 due to classpath

Tags: java, json, jar, websphere, classpath

2 jars in WEB-INF/lib of Websphere  8.5.5.5 are having same directory structure 
org.json.* .

json.jar Compiled withJDK 1.6

commonlib.jar compiled with JDK 1.7

Iam receiving below exception during the JVM startup in one environment while another environment has same jars and same classpath but there its working properly. WAS is running  Java 1.6 due to which getting UnsupportedClassVersionError

**6/23/16 15:59:32:091 CDT] 0000005e InjectionProc W   CWNEN0047W: Resource annotations on the fields of the jmaki.xhp.XmlHttpProxyServlet class will be ignored. The annotations could not be obtained because of the exception : java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=org/json/JSONObject, offset=6**

When i specifically add the second jar to the class path of the second environment it gives the above error, otherwise it works properly Is it due to the classpath order?

[image]

```
class load: org.json.JSONException from: file:/hosting/configs/WebSphereD24/AppServer/installedApps/nodea/sear/swar/WEB-INF/lib/json.jar
class load: org.json.JSONObject$Null from: file:/hosting/configs/WebSphereD24/AppServer/installedApps/nodea/sear/swar/WEB-INF/lib/json.jar
```

How does WebSphere decide the jar to load the class=org/json/JSONException from . This class is present in both the jars... How come its loading from json.jar in one and common.jar in another.

Comment: No, it is due to trying to load 1.7 classes into a 1.6 JVM. Surely this is obvious?

Comment: Well there is another Environment (Server) which identical to the first one. Which runs on Java 1.6 as well.. And has the same jars and classpath. But its not throwing the conflict unless it is explicitley mentioned in classpath as above.

Comment: So the offending JAR isn't being loaded. It is still an incorrect situation with an obvious fix.

Comment: Well fixing isnt the problem here.. How does Websphere decide the jar to load the class=org/json/JSONException from . This class is present in both the jars... How come its loading from json.jar in one and common.jar in another

Comment: If 'fixing isn't the problem', what *is* the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The order of WEB-INF/lib JARs is unspecified, so the order will typically be defined by the file system.  You should remove duplicate classes rather than trying to rely on any particular order.

Comment: Okay. I have mentioned the json.jar in classpath like in the image above .and the issue is resolved. So we cant rely on the WebSphere jar loading.

Comment: @Nayeem Modifying the JVM classpath is not recommended (see the "Classpath" section of the [Java virtual machine settings](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/urun_rconfproc_jvm.html) topic in the Knowledge Center).  The best fix is to remove the JAR causing problems from the WAR.  If that's not possible, [define a shared library](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tcws_sharedlib.html) and associate with the server (or use an isolated shared library with the app).

Comment: Is isolated shared library different from the other one?

Comment: Associating a shared library with the server makes the library available to all applications in the server, but it is in a different class loader than the JVM class loader, so it does not risk breaking the product.  Associating an isolated shared library with the application makes the library only available to those applications.  The end result should be the same.